# Get all user in Websphere portal

Tags: java, atom-feed, websphere-portal

Can I get all user in Websphere portal ? 
I dev on link : http://localhost:10039/wps/contenthandler/um/secure/users/profiles
But some hard
This is :

```
String targetURL = "http://localhost:10039/wps/contenthandler/um/secure/users/profiles";
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
     NodeList nList = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
         doc = db.parse(new URL(targetURL).openStream());
            nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                 Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


                }
               }
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any one can help me 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to get it while running in the context of portal?  if so why use the clunky rest interface and not just call the PUMA SPI directly

```
com.ibm.portal.um.PumaProfile 
com.ibm.portal.um.PumaController 
com.ibm.portal.um.PumaLocator
```

The following sample shows you how to perform the JNDI lookup Either by

```
 Context ctx = new InitialContext();
 Name myjndiname = new CompositeName(PumaHome.JNDI_NAME);
 PumaHome myHome = (PumaHome) ctx.lookup(myjndiname);
```

then you can get that list from the pumalocator by using the findusersbyattribute

or you can just make an xmlaccess requests for users.